# 'No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context.'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to separate my Flask-SQLAlchemy models into separate files. When I try to run `db.create_all()` I get `No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context.`

`shared/db.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from shared.db import db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'My connection string'
db.init_app(app)
```

`user.py`:

```
from shared.db import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = db.Column(db.String(300), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Use `with app.app_context()` to push an application context when creating the tables.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'My connection string'
db.init_app(app)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

Comment: This helped me after the app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
I tried to do it from the console according the SqlAlchemy it can't automatically bind your db to the application - further info here: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/contexts/

Comment: @AnnaSemjén have you found a solution, I added create_app() to flask `__init__py` after it I can create tables and working into flask app, but in terminal I cannot get `User.query.all()`

Comment: I think you need to create the context too - If I remember correctly - >>> from yourapp import create_app
>>> app = create_app()
>>> app.app_context().push()

Comment: what about dropping table? I getting this error when I want to call drop_all() function

Comment: Not working for me. I'm working inside the app file where the context is readily available. Where do we add this? In the worker I cannot add it due to circ dep error. I've added it many places to test anyway, and it doesn't work. Only the worker cannot access context, all other okay. What else can I do?